# Why don't I have "Beta" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I wasn't sure whether I was one of oldest users to participate during beta or not. After analysis, I found this: I posted first question/answer even before some [top beta users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451?phase=beta) signed up. It means that I did participate in the beta.

Why don't I have "beta" badge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The beta badge is for active participation in the *private* beta. You participated in the public beta, but you joined over a month after the private beta was over.

Comment: Fine. Looks like our start was rough: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/16/beta

Comment: The Beta badge isn't awarded on meta. We had [58 users](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/16/beta) earn it on main.

Comment: OMG! I just realized that I looked on meta. Haha..